# Determining all types used by a certain type in c# using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

if I have

```
class A
{
   public void DoStuff()
   {
      B b;
   }
}

struct B {}
struct C {}
```

and I have `typeof(A)`,

I would like to get a list of all types used by A.  in this case it would be `typeof(B)`  and not `typeof(C)`.

Is there a nice way to do this with reflection?

Comment: It's pretty easy to get all types of the _members_ of `A` via `Type.GetFields`, `Type.GetProperties` (or `Type.GetMembers`) and so on.  But figuring out what types are used locally _within_ a method? Not so sure.

Comment: Do you need this at runtime? Do you have access to the code, or do you just have the Type?

Comment: Similar SO Ques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975702/net-reflection-find-used-types

Answer (score 8):

You need to look at the [MethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody) class (there's a very good example of it's use in the link). This will let you write code like:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(A).GetMethod("DoStuff");
MethodBody mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
foreach (LocalVariableInfo lvi in mb.LocalVariables)
{
    if (lvi.LocalType == typeof(B))
        Console.WriteLine("It uses a B!");
    if (lvi.LocalType == typeof(C))
        Console.WriteLine("It uses a C!");
}
```

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear from the post.  I don't want to have to know the fact that B and C exist.  if A also uses D, I'd like to find that out as well.

Comment: As you can see in my code, mb.LocalVariables returns a list of all the types the method uses. That should be exactly what you need to discover if it uses B, C, D or even Z.