# How can I get all types referenced by my assembly?

Tags: .net, reflection

I can get all referenced assemblies, but I have no idea  whether it is possible to find out which concrete types from these assemblies are referenced in my assembly.

Comment: Do you need this to happen at runtime? If so, what are you trying to achieve (there may be other ways). For other options, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975702/net-reflection-find-used-types

Comment: @keyboardP I want to verify my unity container. For that purpose I want to resolve only the types which are directly referenced. Thank you for the link.