# Java: list fields used in a method

Tags: java, reflection, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

In Java, how can I get the Fields that are used in a method ?

Basically, this is the same questions as [this one in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435474/how-can-i-get-fields-used-in-a-method-net). I dont wan't to list the fields from a Class, but to list the fields that are used in a given method of the class.

Example:

```
public class A {
 int a;
 int b;

public int bob(){
 return a-b;
}
```

I want to get the fields like this:

```
Fields[] fields = FieldReader.(A.class.getMethod("bob"));
```

So that `fields[0]=A.a` and `fields[1]=A.b`

I didn't find any solution using standard Reflection. Do you think bytecode manipulation library such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) are a way to go ?

Comment: Could you explain a bit about why you want to do this? There's likely to be an easier way if you can explain the context.

Comment: This is for research purpose, I need to list fields used in a comparator.

Comment: You could use http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html, more specific `visitFieldInst` method. Look on ASM manual, it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) (you need to add it as a dependency, depending on your dependency manager preferences).

This code list the field being accessed in the `public void doSomething();` method.

```
package bcm;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;
import javassist.bytecode.InstructionPrinter;

public class Person {

    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;

    boolean candrink = false;

    public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (this.age > 18) {
            candrink = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            CannotCompileException {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            CtClass cc = pool.get("bcm.Person");
            CtMethod m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething", null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
            InstructionPrinter i = new InstructionPrinter(ps);
            i.print(m);
            String content = baos.toString();

            for (String line : content.split("\\r?\\n")) {
                if (line.contains("getfield")) {
                    System.out.println(line.replaceAll("getfield ", ""));
                }
            }

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Once you load a classnode this becomes incredibly easy.

```
// Assuming you have loaded classNode
for (MethodNode method : classNode.methods){
    for (AbstractInsnNode ain : method.instructions.toArray()) {
        if (ain.getType() == AbstractInsnNode.FIELD_INSN) {
            FieldInsnNode fin = (FieldInsnNode) ain;
            //fin.name = Field name
            //fin.owner = ClassNode's name
        }
    }
}
```

Plus ASM is much faster than libraries such as Javassist.

Comment: Since performance is a concern, I might switch to this solution. I will perform some tests to compare both approaches